# Variable Assignment Not Working as Expected

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a code that searches through a range of numbers and figures out if a user inputed number is in the range. I'm using a binary search to do this.

Here is what I've written:

```
initial = 0
final = 10000
guess = (initial + final)//2

num = int(input("Enter Number"))

while True:
    if guess == num:
        print(guess, "is in our list. Congratulation!")
        break
    elif guess > num:
        final = guess
    else:
        initial = guess
```

The above program runs infinitely, as the variable guess does not evaluate to the new value of either final or initial after the first iteration.

I tried adjusting the code without variables as shown bellow, and it worked.

```
initial = 0
final = 1000

guess = (initial + final)//2
num = int(input("Enter Number"))

while True:
    if (initial + final)//2 == num:
        print((initial + final)//2, "is in our list. Congratulation!")
        break
    elif (initial + final)//2 > num:
        final = (initial + final)//2

    else:
        initial = (initial + final)//2
```

I can't understand why the variable guess is not changing.

I thought I understood variable assignment until this problem came up.

Comment: You need to update your `guess` variable *in the loop*. Variables are not 'live', the *result* is assigned, not the expression.

Comment: Ok thank. This makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable needs to be updated with every iteration. Move it into the while loop. Right now you only evaluate it once at the start.